# Is is possible to update APK and Store Listing before Publish in the NEW Android Developer Console?

Tags: android, developer-console

The "NEW Developer Console" is now the standard for all users. So we must all deal with the changes in behavior from the old console. You used to be able to upload and release an APK update and update your store listing in one step. I cannot figure out how to do that in the new console.

This is what I tried:

1. I uploaded my apk using the "Simple Mode", but was then prompted to "Publish Now" before getting a chance to change the store listing (e.g. recent changes).
2. I changed to "Advanced Mode" and was able to upload my apk and save as a draft. I then tried to access the Store Listing, but this said that I could not save changes since I had archived or reactivated one or more apks.
3. I changed tactics. I started with going to Store Listing and modified my recent changes. Then I tried going to the APK area to upload my new version and it says that it can't save the Store Listing without publishing.

Am I missing something? Please explain.

Comment: This had been closed as not a question, but I want an answer to what the OP asked. I removed the rant and left only the question. Please reopen/answer.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same thing with the new developer console.  However, it doesn't matter that they don't let you publish both at the same time since it takes a couple hours before the store updates with your changes anyways.  When I see the store update from changes, I always see it update to all of the changes at once, even though they were "published" separately (assuming you have them all made before the store updates).